# I´m trying to print a table of values using google colab however the image is too low definition, is there any way to fix that?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

A professor gave me a code in google colab at the end it should print a table of values.
here is the bit of code that should print:

```
# Montagem da tabela 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
data=[[N[0], lista_f[0][0], lista_f[0][1], lista_f[0][2]],
      [N[1], lista_f[1][0], lista_f[1][1], lista_f[1][2]],
      [N[2], lista_f[2][0], lista_f[2][1], lista_f[2][2]],
      [N[3], lista_f[3][0], lista_f[3][1], lista_f[3][2]],
      [N[4], lista_f[4][0], lista_f[4][1], lista_f[4][2]]]
column_labels = ["Discretizações", "1º Frequência", "2º Frequência", "3º Frequência"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column_labels)
ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')
ax.table(cellText=df.values,
        colLabels=df.columns,
        colColours =["yellow"] * 4,
        cellLoc="center")
plt.show()
```

The `pd` is pandas lib and `plt` is matplotlib.
I´ve tried using `figsize(x,y)` to make it bigger, but it didnt work, I'm kinda lost, any help is apreciated

Comment: pass `figsize=(x, y)` to `plt.subplots`

Comment: try this. `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, dpi=300)` You can increase the resolution by setting it to the dpi value required for printing.